# Analytics in sql

Tags: sql, postgresql, self-join

I have a table with the following structure:
      `use_id (int) - event (str) - time (timestamp) - value (int)`

Event can take several values : install, login, buy, etc.

I need to get all user records before updating the application. 
For example moment of release of my application - 1 January 2019, but users may be install new version on any day.

How can i get `sum(value)` by the first and second versions. ---------

I tried self-join table, but I think that this is not the best solution.

Help me, please.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.  You mention things like "update", "first and second version" and it is entirely unclear how these are represented in the data.

Comment: For example I have 3 versions of my app. First version release date - 1 January 2018, second - 1 June 2018, and third 1 January 2019. I need to compare version one and version two. To use the new version, the user must install it. As a result, the following line appears in the table: `<user_id> - install - 2018-10-25 18:33:12 - 0`. This means that the user has installed (or updated) 2018-10-25. But the user could not install the updated version and continue to use the old one. So I need to sum up all `values` for two versions

Answer (score 0):

Here is the definition of your table (as I understood it from your comments and description):

```
CREATE TABLE user_events (
   user_id integer,
   event varchar,
  time timestamp without time zone,
  value integer
);
```

Here is the query you asked for:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(user_id),
    SUM(value)
FROM (
    SELECT 
        DISTINCT ON (user_id)
        user_id,time,value
    FROM user_events
    WHERE event='install'
    ORDER BY user_id, time DESC
) last_installations
WHERE 
    time BETWEEN date '2018-01-01' AND date '2019-01-01';
```

Some explanations:

- inner query ( `last_installations` ) selects last install events for each user
- outer query filters out only installations of first and second versions, and calculates `SUM(value)` (as you asked) and `COUNT(user_id)` (I added for clarity - how many users are using 1 and 2 versions now)

### UPDATE

sum value for all events by version

```
SELECT 
    event,
    CASE 
        WHEN  time BETWEEN date '2018-01-01' AND timestamp '2018-05-30 23:59:59' THEN 1
        WHEN  time BETWEEN date '2018-06-01' AND timestamp '2018-12-31 23:59:59' THEN 2
        WHEN  time > date '2018-01-01'                                           THEN 3
        ELSE 0 -- unknown version 
    END AS version,
    SUM(value)
FROM user_events
GROUP BY 1,2
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but is's a little unfaithful. I need to sum value for all events by version

Comment: The problem is that you need to install the application to use it. It may happen that 2018-12-31 the user uses the first version of the application

Comment: I think you should clearly describe what you want. What is the meaning of 'value' field ? Does the 'time' field uniquely identifies version? If not, how can we know the version?  And, finally, what is the results that you want?

Comment: the 'value' field is a numeric field, for example revenue. The version determines when it is installed, similar to mobile apps. That is, you can use the old version, if you do not install the new one. The installation corresponds to a row in the table where event= 'install'.